# Pentaho - Replace in String Regex -- "Replace with" is not supporting Regex

Tags: pentaho, kettle

In Pentaho PDI, Replace in String step is not supporting regex in "Replace with"Column.

[Execution Result :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEiQG.png)

[Replace In String :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu1qP.png)

Comment: seems like issue with regular expression, check online with any of regex tools and verify whether it is proper or not.

Comment: @Working Hard : I have used the same regular expression in notepad++ and it works fine.Basically the search "(?:(\{)|(A)|(B)|(C)|(D)|(E)|(F)|(G)|(H)|(I))(?!\S)" regex find the last character of my String and the replace with "(?{1}0:?{2}1:?{3}2:?{4}3:?{5}4:?{6}5:?{7}6:?{8}7:?{9}8:9)"  regex replace the last value as per the condition provided.

Comment: @Working Hard... Any suggestions...??

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Javascript` step. Regexp in javascript are easier to write and gives a more predictable result.

Answer (score 0):

The "Replace with" field doesn't allow what you're doing. You can use things like `$1`, which replaces by the 1st capture group, or `$1-$3` which would replace by 1st group and 3rd group separated by dash, but that's about it. You will need to either re-evaluate your logic or use a different step for the regex matching and replacing (e.g., Java script, or User defined java expression).